# Name for pattern T | Array<T>

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript, naming-conventions

A common pattern that libraries use is accepting a type or an array of that type as an argument to a function. For example:

```
interface JQuery {
    add(selector: HTMLElement | HTMLElement[]): this;
}
```

Is there a name for this pattern? I'd like to alias it to improve readability. My first guess is `TypeOrArray<T>` but this sounds clunky and may potentially be unintuitive.

***Note***: I've tagged this `typescript` *since that's what I'm using and something idiomatic may be a better answer. However, this should apply to any language that makes use of generics.*

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is typescript's way of allowing you to define multiple types for a single parameter.

In your case the **selector** can be either an HTMLElement or an Array of HTMLElement.

The same you can do for any type:

```js
function example(parameter: number | string) {

}

example(5) // works

example('2') // works

example(new Date()) // fails
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the pattern actually is "type or array of the type".

It's more like "whatever the author of the library considered to be convenient for its users".

Typescript union type fits pretty good here, it allows you to describe whatever combination of types is acceptable for particular function, without thinking too much about names.

If you inclined to name your types, the appropriate name could be

```
type HTMLElementsToAdd = HTMLElement | HTMLElement[];
```

The purpose is to indicate that the type is not just an element array, and is specific to `add` method. Cursory look through jQuery API docs confirms that it hardly follows any specific pattern, and actually uses "or" to describe acceptable types, [for example](https://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
.append( content [, content ] )
 content 
 Type: htmlString or Element or Text or Array or jQuery
```